# How can I validate a List/Array Count in an MVC Model using Data Annotations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

How would one go about validating a nested List of Objects in an MVC Model?

I have an "Item" object which has an attached List of Revenue Entries:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    public virtual List<RevenueEntryModel> Revenues { get; set;}
}
```

This list can be edited on the page dynamically, and each item is validated individually using it's own model - "RevenueEntryModel". However, I want to be able to restrict users from entering Items without any Revenues.

Is it possible to validate whether this Revenues list is empty using Data Annotations? I'm already using [Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) but I'm pretty sure it doesn't include this functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ViewModel validation for a List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146732/viewmodel-validation-for-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

There's a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5146766/1147593) that will help you here. It's a thorough answer, but basically you need to use custom validation attributes:

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your own logic that checks the number of items in the Revenues collection.

Apply a class level validation attribute to the ItemModel class. You could use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CustomValidationAttribute for this.

This points to a custom method you would create.

The attribute construct would look something like this:

```
[CustomValidation(typeof (MyClassWhereMethodIsLocated), "MyStaticMethodName")]
```

Checkout [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/peterblum/archive/2009/12/07/the-customvalidationattribute.aspx) for additional details