# How to validate number of items in a list in mvc model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am writing an online assessment form. On this form the user has to select a minimum of 3 and a maximum of 7 people who will provide an assessment on them. I have a form where the user adds the assessors and I display the list underneath this form. Once the user has finished adding assessors then click on the self assessment button to fill his/hers own self assessment.

What I want to do is to validate that indeed the number of assessors is in the right range before the user leaves the page.

The model is like this

```
public class AssessorsViewModel
{
    List<Assessor> Assessors { get; set; }
}

public class Assessor
{
    string Email { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have validation attributes for the Assessor class so everytime the user adds an assessor I can validate this, but I can't figure out how to validate the Count on the Assessors List.

I am using ASP.net MVC.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [ViewModel validation for a List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146732/viewmodel-validation-for-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply validate this in the controller:

```
public ActionResult TheAction(AssessorsViewModel model)
{
    if (model.Assessors == null
        || model.Assessors.Count < 3
        || model.Assessors.Count > 7)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Assessors", "Please enter note less than 3 and not more than 7 assessors.");
        return View(model);
    }
    ...
}
```

Another option would be to write a custom validation attribute. Here is an [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/peterblum/archive/2009/12/07/the-customvalidationattribute.aspx) of how to do this (the validator there is different, but the approach is clear).

Answer (score 18):

A custom ValidationAttribute would do it for you:

```
public class LimitCountAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int _min;
    private readonly int _max;

    public LimitCountAttribute(int min, int max) {
        _min = min;
        _max = max;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value) {
        var list = value as IList;
        if (list == null)
            return false;

        if (list.Count < _min || list.Count > _max)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class AssessorsViewModel
{
    [LimitCount(3, 7, ErrorMessage = "whatever"]
    List<Assessor> Assessors { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This one didn't seem to work the value on the IsValid method is always  0.

Answer (score 2):

You could always add a custom validation attribute that would get fired when the model is validated.

Check the answer here on another question:
[ASP.NET MVC: Custom Validation by DataAnnotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100300/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-by-data-annonation)