# ASP.NET MVC List validation in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 ViewModels:

```
public class AViewModel
{
   public string Text {get; set;}
   //some other properties
}
```

And:

```
public class BViewModel
{
   public List<AViewModel> List {get; set;}
   //some other properties
}
```

I'm passing `BViewModel` to `View` and by default displaying 4 inputs for my list. I would like to achieve that validation is successful only if 2 or more inputs are non-empty, so my `List` in viewmodel must contain 2 `AViewModel` objects which have non-empty `Text` property.
How can I achieve that?
Should I try to write custom validation attribute or is there any other way?

Comment: Are you trying to do server side only? client-side only? or both? if you are looking at doing both, you are best off trying to write your own. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146732/viewmodel-validation-for-a-list, here's a good place to start.

Comment: A custom validation attribute would be best, but you can always just check the collection in the POST method and add a `ModelStateError` is not valid and return the view. Either way you will not get client side vaidation. For that you will need to write your own client side scripts to display an error message.