# ASP.NET Web API: Array vs. List<T>

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I had a property `LineItems` which was of type `List<LineItem>`, it was `[Required]`. We realized that it was possible to send an empty array via JSON (`"lineItems": []`) which was not what we wanted to achieve with the `[Required]` attribute.

I've thought about a solution, maybe a custom filter but then I found out that it is possible to use `[MinLength(1)]`. Unfortunately only in the case of an array (`LineItem[]`).

My Question now is: Are there any arguments to favor one type over the other regarding the interface?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5146766/4275342

Comment: Thanks, found that already. But I think I would favor the built in solution if there is no downside for an array.

Comment: I don't think there is some in built one that you can use right out of the box. Going for a custom attribute for yourself would be probably better. :)