# How to limit the number tags an author can insert

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I am currently building a blog using asp.net core. I understand I can limit the length of the string used in the title, using data annotation.  How can I limit the number of tags input by a user? For example, you can only input a maximum of 5 tags here, on stackoverflow.

```
  public class Post
        {
            public int PostId { get; set; }

            [MaximumLength(50)] 
            public string Title { get; set; }

            public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
        }


   public class PostTag
       {
         public int TagId { get; set; }
         public Tag Tag { get; set; }

         public int PostId { get; set; }
         public Post Post { get; set;}
         }



    public class Tag
    {
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set }
```

Comment: You would have to write code to do that, there is nothing that is built in.

Comment: What about adding something like Enumerable.TakeWhile<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)

Comment: You can write a custom validator, for hint look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146732/viewmodel-validation-for-a-list/5146766#5146766). You can also find many existing questions if you search a bit.

Answer (score 0):

simple put you need to wrote code that will restrict it.  The method in which you do that will depend greatly on how you want to populate it.

Heres a simple example of how I would do it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Posts
        {
            public Posts()
            {
                _tags = new List<string>();
            }

            private List<string> _tags { get;}

            public List<string> Tags
            {
                get { return _tags ; }
            }

            public bool AddTag(string tag)
            {
                var maxTag = 5; // put in config

                if (_tags.Count() + 1 > maxTag)
                {
                    //throw new Exception("unable to add tag... too many tags");
                    return false;
                }

                _tags.Add(tag);
                return true;
            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            // limit tags to 5

            var post = new Posts();

            for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(post.AddTag(a.ToString())
                    ? "Added " + a + " to the tags"
                    : "Failed to add " + a + " to the tags");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

basically I have a tags property in the model, but its only accessible through methods in the class.  This will prevent circumvention of the add/get methods.

the results from the main look like this.

```
Added 0 to the tags
Added 1 to the tags
Added 2 to the tags
Added 3 to the tags
Added 4 to the tags
Failed to add 5 to the tags
Failed to add 6 to the tags
Failed to add 7 to the tags
Failed to add 8 to the tags
Failed to add 9 to the tags
```

Let me know if this helps